# Can I group items in a legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have this bar chart I made using:

```
ggplot(ViralReads, aes(x=Host, y=Reads, fill=Taxon)) +
  geom_col(colour = "black", position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_percent())+
  theme_minimal()
```

For each "taxon" there is a category 'Genome' associated with it. I would like to group the items in the legend by 'Genome'. Anyone know if this is possible to do? I tried to play around with the legend a

Here is reproducible data as requested!

```
structure(list(Host = c("Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", 
"Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", 
"Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", 
"Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", 
"Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", 
"Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", 
"Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Ochlerotatus", 
"Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", 
"Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", 
"Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", 
"Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", 
"Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", 
"Ochlerotatus", "Ochlerotatus", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", 
"Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", 
"Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", 
"Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", 
"Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", 
"Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", "Coquillettidia", 
"Coquillettidia"), Genome = c("(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", 
"(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", 
"(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", 
"(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "dsRNA", "dsRNA", 
"dsRNA", "ssDNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", 
"(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", 
"(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", 
"(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "dsRNA", "dsRNA", "dsRNA", 
"ssDNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", 
"(-)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", 
"(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", 
"(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "dsRNA", "dsRNA", "dsRNA", "ssDNA", "(-)ssRNA", 
"(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(-)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", 
"(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", 
"(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", "(+)ssRNA", 
"dsRNA", "dsRNA", "dsRNA", "ssDNA"), Reads = c(102317, 163616, 
6188, 130, 0, 0, 195632, 38928, 51823, 4033, 71500, 0, 0, 102317, 
3953, 363, 52677, 62, 4033, 5183, 1542, 0, 4313, 1071, 36260, 
0, 10089, 0, 0, 84154, 0, 814, 0, 82223, 281910, 60584, 1071, 
8802, 0, 2203, 0, 0, 0, 622680, 0, 2229, 0, 0, 0, 550, 0, 0, 
1445303, 0, 0, 0, 960293, 16515, 470781, 0, 0, 701, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 352, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1186, 138498, 200, 0, 197, 2640, 
0, 0, 352, 0, 0, 0, 0, 197, 0, 3752, 0, 10899), Taxon = c("Orthomyxoviridae", 
"Rhabdoviridae", "Peribunyaviridae", "Chuviridae", "Phasmaviridae", 
"Phenuiviridae", "Iflaviridae", "Luteoviridae", "Tombusviridae", 
"Nodaviridae", "Unclassified Picornavirales", "Negevirus", "Tymoviridae", 
"Virgaviridae", "Dicistroviridae", "Totiviridae", "Flaviviridae", 
"Narnaviridae", "Nodaviridae", "Partitiviridae", "Birnaviridae", 
"Reoviridae", "Parvoviridae", "Orthomyxoviridae", "Rhabdoviridae", 
"Peribunyaviridae", "Chuviridae", "Phasmaviridae", "Phenuiviridae", 
"Iflaviridae", "Luteoviridae", "Tombusviridae", "Nodaviridae", 
"Unclassified Picornavirales", "Negevirus", "Tymoviridae", "Virgaviridae", 
"Dicistroviridae", "Totiviridae", "Flaviviridae", "Narnaviridae", 
"Nodaviridae", "Partitiviridae", "Birnaviridae", "Reoviridae", 
"Parvoviridae", "Orthomyxoviridae", "Rhabdoviridae", "Peribunyaviridae", 
"Chuviridae", "Phasmaviridae", "Phenuiviridae", "Iflaviridae", 
"Luteoviridae", "Tombusviridae", "Nodaviridae", "Unclassified Picornavirales", 
"Negevirus", "Tymoviridae", "Virgaviridae", "Dicistroviridae", 
"Totiviridae", "Flaviviridae", "Narnaviridae", "Nodaviridae", 
"Partitiviridae", "Birnaviridae", "Reoviridae", "Parvoviridae", 
"Orthomyxoviridae", "Rhabdoviridae", "Peribunyaviridae", "Chuviridae", 
"Phasmaviridae", "Phenuiviridae", "Iflaviridae", "Luteoviridae", 
"Tombusviridae", "Nodaviridae", "Unclassified Picornavirales", 
"Negevirus", "Tymoviridae", "Virgaviridae", "Dicistroviridae", 
"Totiviridae", "Flaviviridae", "Narnaviridae", "Nodaviridae", 
"Partitiviridae", "Birnaviridae", "Reoviridae", "Parvoviridae"
)), row.names = c(NA, -92L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer here is "no", you can't have grouped legends within ggplot natively.

However, the long answer is "yes, but it isn't easy". It requires creating a bunch of plots (one per genome) and harvesting their legends, then stitching them back onto the main plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

fill_df <- ViralReads %>% 
  select(-1, -3) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(color = scales::hue_pal()(22))

legends <- lapply(split(ViralReads, ViralReads$Genome), function(x) {
  genome <- x$Genome[1]
  patchwork::wrap_elements(full = cowplot::get_legend(
    ggplot(x, aes(Host, Reads, fill = Taxon)) + 
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = genome, 
    values = setNames(fill_df$color[fill_df$Genome == genome],
                      fill_df$Taxon[fill_df$Genome == genome])) +
    theme(legend.justification = c(0, 1))))
})

p1 <- ggplot(ViralReads, aes(x=Host, y=Reads, fill=Taxon)) +
  geom_col(colour = "black", position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent())+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p1 + ((legends[[1]] + legends[[2]]) / (legends[[3]] + legends[[4]]))
```

[image]

Unfortunately, 22 different colors is just too many to use as a discrete color scale. I would probably use a different way of visualising these data, perhaps something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ViralReads %>%
  filter(Reads > 0) %>%
  mutate(Taxon = sub("Unclassified", "misc", Taxon)) %>%
  mutate(Taxon = reorder(factor(Taxon), as.numeric(factor(Genome)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Taxon, Reads, fill = Genome)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_log10(labels = scales::comma, name = "Reads (log scale)") +
  facet_wrap(.~Host, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 8),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "gray90"))
```

[image]

Anyway, it's good to know that grouped legends are at least possible in ggplot, so thanks for the OP.

Comment: It depends on the message that you want the plot to convey. I struggle to see any clear message except "there are a diverse range of viruses with different types of genome seen in these 4 genera of mosquito". Did you have a message in mind?

Comment: My main takeaway is that I want to show differences in diversity (e.g., Culex has the most diverse virome), and general proportions of reads for each (e.g., for Aedes, birnaviridae makes up half of all viral reads; Iflaviruses dominate Coquillettidia). This is basically the summary of a large metatranscriptomics project and people in literature have either used a bar chart or a treemap, so I am totally open to better ways to present this!